# In The Force Awakens what is the ranking order of the Storm Troopers?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

First off there is the standard armour:[image]

Notice the flat shoulder pads, next we have

[image: Storm trooper flat shoulder]

Notice the larger shoulder pad.

Also through the movie I noticed the same larger shoulder pad coloured in both Black at one point and Red at one point.

We also have Phasmas crazy chrome armour.

**What is the ranking order for these armour types? Who commands who?**

Comment: From what I remember: Trooper, Sergeant and Captain not sure what other ranks eist though

Comment: @TonyMeyer good find :)

Comment: Out of cannon but in the games (Jedi outcast, and battlefront) the yellow shoulder pad is worn by heavy weapons units. It could be another of the minor armour changes that are seen in the films, (Yellow shoulders on Tattoene mask on Hoth and a visor on Endor).

Comment: Out of cannon but in the games (Jedi outcast, and battlefront) the yellow shoulder pad is worn by heavy weapons units. It could be another of the minor armour changes that are seen in the films, (Yellow shoulders on Tattoene mask on Hoth and a visor on Endor (but in Endor only for the original garrison, the counter attack wore regular armour)).

Comment: @Thomas Trooper, Sergeant, Captain, Commander, then General is what I remember from TCW series, and there would be little reason to change this.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan yepp although I don't remember ANY stormtrooper of any kind becoming commander or general. On a second thought though I think it is COMMANDER  for one of the clone troopers once....so commander could be possible there but general I'm not sure about

Comment: @Thomas The average stormtrooper would likely not become a general. In TCW generals were mainly Jedi and special civilians trained to command. I am sure the Empire has command schools to train people in the art of commanding large numbers of troops. Then again, this is all just guessed at by looking at the easily observed command structure in the GAR, and is not sufficient for an answer. I imagine the best Stormtrooper commanders could have gotten promoted to lead larger forces - in effect becoming generals.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan the problem is clone troopers like cody,.... were in effect commanding all but the ships while the jedi generals commanded both the ships and the ground forces.  so from there in essence cody was what would be a modern day ground forces general I would dare say despite his commander rank. but yepp we just dont have enough infos so far to truly answer sadly